# Django tabular inline is very slow

Tags: django

I found an admin page with a tabular inline is very slow.

The inline widget has 20 lines and each line has 15 fields.

I got this result with debug toolbar.
[image]

It takes Total: 81121.01ms while sql only takes 177 queries in 1709.65ms.

Render template consumes most of time, and if I remove `{{field.field}}` in `tabular.html`, the page takes less than 2000ms.

So how can I improve it?

Comment: Can you share your models and admin.py?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I got the problem, the inline contains a `ForeignKey` whcih have thousands of choices. After I add it to autocomplete field, the page load fast.